# PHP array push to array but keep existing sequence

Tags: php, arrays

I have this 2 array:

```
$array1 = [3,6,5];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

I want to achieve this:

```
$newArray = [3,6,5,1,2,4];
```

so it keep the sequence and append the missing value on `$array1`.

```
    foreach($array1 as $data){
        if(!in_array($data, $array2)){
            array_push($array2, $data);
        }
    }
```

I try above code but what i got is my array become double.

Any solution?

Comment: i just updated my answer. it works as you asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this,

```
$newArray = array_unique(array_merge($array1 ,$array2));
```

This array_merge() function use for merge one or more arrays into one array and array_unique() function removes duplicate values from an array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$array1 = [3,6,5];
$array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);
$newArray = array_merge($array1, $diff);
```

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

To stay with your existing approach, you need to change your logic:

```
foreach($array2 as $data){
    if(!in_array($data, $array1)){
        array_push($array1, $data);
        //or
        //$array1[] = $data;
    }
}
```